# avoiding going back to main thread after opening camera android

Tags: java, android, camera

So I'm programming my first app, and I have a loading screen which shows my logo and a loading bar. This is actually just for the looks.
But when I want to take a picture with the camera, and inserting it into an imageview, it goes back to the loading screen, and not to my second screen after pressing ok button in the camera app.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

my code:

second activity:

```
public void makeFoto(View v) {
    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST);
    photoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvFoto);
            imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            //HttpGetMethod client = new HttpGetMethod();

        }
    }
}
```

loading screen:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_screen);
        (new Thread(){
            @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int i = 0; i<255; i++){
                // next will pause the thread for some time
                try{ sleep(5); }
                   catch(Exception e)

                   { break; }
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(LoadScreen.this,Home.class));
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Yep, because everyone else is doing it. Hard to tell what you did wrong without your code though.

Comment: make sure u are start camera from Second Activity instead of from Loading Screen?

Comment: Yes I started the activity from Second Activity.
I'll upload the code later on.
And I'm also having the same problem after every Intent...

Comment: can anyone please help?

Comment: I had a noHistory statement in my manifest file, which caused this...